# Java RCP - Not able to dynamically set text to SWT label control

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

In one of our rcp application's window, I need to set label text dynamically after the creation of the window.

When the window is created I would have created the label control but I would not set the text by then. After user selects a button on the window, I want to set the text of the label inside the button's selection listener method. After setting text to label inside button's selection listener method I am not able to see the text on the window.

Why is that I am not able to see the label text on the window when I set it inside the listener method? Is it because the window is already created?

how do I solve this?

Comment: could you please add your code here? without code is hard to find out what is the cause exactly

Comment: Selecting a button? are you talking about a radio button? normal buttons are just clicked, they cant be selected.

Answer (score 5):

The Size of the Label is not getting updated after the call to `setText()`. Try calling `parent.layout()` after `setText()` where the `parent` is the `Composite` containing your label control.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is something to do with  how you layout the label. after setting text on `Label`, do re-layout or adjust its bounds.